# how can i change the src of an image after using slideUp()

Tags: html, jquery

I wanted to `slideUp()` the image (a sun image) as the user clicks on it, then change the `src` of the image so that when I use `slideDown()` the new image (a moon) would show. It would appear as if the sun set and the moon took its place.

However the `src` doesn't change. It changes only after I click again. It would `slideUp` and `slideDown` with the same image. Please help I am new to coding

```js
$("body").click(function() {
  $(".Sunclouds").slideUp();

  var source = $(".Sunclouds").attr("src");
  if (source === "Images/sunclouds.svg") {
    $(".Sunclouds").attr("src", "Images/moonstars.svg");
    $(".Sunclouds").attr("alt", "moon_stars");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".top-div").css("background-color", "#010737");
      $(".top-div").css("color", "white");
      $(".Sunclouds").addClass("marginBottom");
    }, 100);
    $(".Sunclouds").slideDown();
  } else {
    $(".Sunclouds").attr("src", "Images/sunclouds.svg");
    $(".Sunclouds").attr("alt", "sun_clouds");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".top-div").css("background-color", "rgba(243, 241, 161, 0.53)");
      $(".top-div").css("color", "black");
      $(".Sunclouds").removeClass("marginBottom");
    }, 100);
    $(".Sunclouds").slideDown();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top-div">
  <img class="Sunclouds" src="Images\sunclouds.svg" alt="sun_clouds">
  <h1>I'm Yaqoob</h1>
  <h2 class="devh2">a Developer</h2>
  <img class="Sea_image" src="Images\sea new.svg" alt="sea_image">
</div>
```

Comment: I would try changing `attr` to `prop` when changing `src`.

Comment: Could you please include all relevant HTML in the question

Comment: If it works the second time calling a hack would be calling it twice, or try calling it from your setTimeout function. Alternatively you could try using 2 css classes with different background images instead of image src change.

Answer (score 0):

Is suncloud your background?

Than you should switch to css background.

Otherwise see comment of @imvain2